# Pushing to session array with custom key

Tags: php, laravel

If I have a session value which is an array, I know I can just push to it, but can I push to it with a custom key?

Basicaly I wanna do something like the following (which doesn't work):

```
$request->session()->push('cart', 'customKey' => $productInfo);
```

Comment: Is the cart an array or a collection?

Answer (score 1):

You have to store key and value in array and use it like this below:

```
$request->session()->push('cart', ['customKey' => $productInfo]);
```

Comment: I know that but I don't wanna do that because I get another array inside the existing array with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

use Session; in Model and Controller

```
// Via a request instance...

$request->session()->put('key', 'value');

// Via the global helper...

session(['key' => 'value']);
```

for more details [Manual](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I've tested

```
Route::get('/checkSession',function(){
    $items= ['item1','item2'];
    session()->push('cart',["customKey" => $items ]);
    foreach (Session::get('cart') as $key){
        //dump($key["customKey"]);
        foreach ($key["customKey"] as $key1 ) {
            dump($key1);
        }
    }
    session()->forget('cart');
    session()->flush('cart');
    dd("STOP");
});
```

Comment: I know that, I am talking about specifically using push to add an element with a custom key. Not a whole new array, just an element into an existing array but with a custom key.

Comment: please give it a try and let me know